# compute average of the first item in two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this two dimensional array

```
var data = [
['12-9', 134],
['12-9', 148],
['12-9', 92],
['1-8', 116],
['1-8', 136],
['1-8', 150],
['21-5', 138],
['21-5', 143],
['21-5', 119],
['21-5', 125]
]
```

and I if the first value of an item matches the one of the others I want to compute the averrage of the second one.

e.g.: th e first 3 elements all have "12-9" and for that it should give me 124,7 because (137+148+92) / 3 = 124,7.

This might be very easy but I'm stuck. I tried it with map() and reduce() or filter() but nothing works for me. I'm very shure that I not to see the obvious things here.

And now I dumped everything down again and this is my new starting point now:

```
  for (let item of data) {
    var temp = item[0];
    var myValues = data.filter((value) => {
      return value[0] === temp;
    });
    console.log(myValues );
  }
```

Comment: You will need to gather/accumulate the data under that first column's content first - either in form of an array, that you put these 134, 148, 92 values into (so that you can get the sum, and length of that array later), or directly sum the values up, but then you will need to keep track of the count yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter and reduce is what you need

```js
const data = [['12-9', 134],['12-9', 148],['12-9', 92],['1-8', 116],['1-8', 136],['1-8', 150],['21-5', 138],['21-5', 143],['21-5', 119],['21-5', 125]];

const avg = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const key = item[0]
  if (!acc[key]) {
    const same = data
      .filter(nums => nums[0] === key);

    acc[key] = {
      count: same.length,
      avg: +(same.reduce((acc, [key, num]) => acc + num, 0) / same.length).toFixed(2) // key is ignored we could use an underscore to show that
    }
  }
  return acc
}, {})
console.log(avg)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example reducing into a Map grouped by the first element, and then iterating over the result to average the grouped arrays and rebuild the shape of the original array.

```js
const data = [['12-9', 134], ['12-9', 148], ['12-9', 92], ['1-8', 116], ['1-8', 136], ['1-8', 150], ['21-5', 138], ['21-5', 143], ['21-5', 119], ['21-5', 125],];

const map = data.reduce((a, [k, v]) => a.set(k, [...(a.get(k) ?? []), v]), new Map());

const result = [...map.entries()].map(([k, vs]) => [k, vs.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / vs.length]);

console.log(result);
```

Or similar logic applied in successive `for...of` loops, but this time tracking a running sum and count of each element thus avoiding the later reduce to calculate the average.

```js
const data = [['12-9', 134], ['12-9', 148], ['12-9', 92], ['1-8', 116], ['1-8', 136], ['1-8', 150], ['21-5', 138], ['21-5', 143], ['21-5', 119], ['21-5', 125],];

const map = new Map();
for (const [key, value] of data) {
  if (!map.has(key)) {
    map.set(key, { sum: 0, count: 0 });
  }

  map.get(key).count += 1;
  map.get(key).sum += value;
}

const result = [];
for (const [key, { sum, count }] of map) {
  result.push([key, sum / count]);
}

console.log(result);
```